# Where to find a medical alert system without monthly payment?

Tags: medical-device, emergency, home-medical-equipment

I have been using alert1 for awhile, but recently my liabilities increase as my daughter suddenly got divorce. I am not sure how long will this last, but I plan to replace my mom's medical alert to the one without monthly subscription fee. I am fine with any brand as long as they carry the panic button necklace, and I also do not mind if the new system can only contact my phone number and some other numbers. Thank you

Answer This Question

Comment: I will be very surprised if such a thing exists.

Comment: @careyGregory how about some panic button that can at the very least water proof and can call my cellphone when pressed?

Comment: I think the name for that is a cell phone. Most cell phones can be set up to call a certain number by pressing a single digit for 2+ seconds. You can buy inexpensive prepaid cell phones for very little money.

Comment: @careygregory yeah I agree with you, but I think cellphone is not waterproof and kinda big and heavy